# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

А ради этого стоит посетить Америку!
 Особенно красив он зимой, когда скалы и края реки покрываются широким слоем льда, а на гребне водопада прямо на глазах вырастают сосульки и сталактиты.

Comment: А чем в данном тексте, интересно, отличаются сталактиты от сосулек? Сосульки по сути - это разновидность сталактитов.

Comment: Ну, в данном случае все-таки сосульки. Сталактиты предполагают камень

Answer (score 1):

Знаки поставлены правильно.